# Common prefix for multiple matches

Tags: ruby, regex

Suppose I have the following test string:

```
I want to match:
  123
  456
```

I want to use a regex to capture `123` and `456`.

I'm trying this:

```
I want to match:(?:\n\s\s(\d*))*
```

but it only captures the last group. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
I want to match:\K|\G(?!^)(?:\n\s\s(\d+))
```

You can use `\G` for this as regex engine only remembers the last group.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pG1kU1/13

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String#scan`

```
s = <<-STR
  123
  456
STR

s.scan /\d+/    #=> ["123", "456"]
s.scan /(\d+)/  #=> [["123"], ["456"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you match the part `I want to match:` in the string, your next matching point will be somewhere after that. This means that you can only match once with that regex, given the format of your test string.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot get all the captured values of a capture group.
A good explanation is [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html#groupnumbers), where it says:

> **The Returned Value for a Given Group is the Last One Captured**
>   Since a capture group with a quantifier holds on to its number, what value does the engine return when you inspect the group? All engines return the last value captured. For instance, if you match the string A_B_C_D_ with ([A-Z]*)+, when you inspect the match, Group 1 will be D*. With the exception of the .NET engine, all intermediate values are lost. In essence, Group 1 gets overwritten each time its pattern is matched.

So, if you know that the lines you want to capture will at most be 2, then you may try something like this:

```
I want to match:(?:\n\s\s(\d*))?(?:\n\s\s(\d*))?
```

i.e. manually repeat the capture group for each line.

Answer (score -1):

You can capture your example string like this: `\n*\s*(\d+)`